# System Call Entries in Linux 3.14

Tags: linux, system-calls

Where do system call entries locate in Linux Kernel 3.14? In former distributions, there should be a .S file listing the entries of system calls, as below:

`.long sys_restart_syscall    /*0*/`

`.long sys_exit`

`.long sys_fork`

...

Answer (score 0):

For X86, system call entries will be located in `arch/x86/syscalls/` folder.

Reference
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl?v=3.14